# Bootstrap Alerts in PartialView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, view, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have *PartialView* and I renders the specified partial view - *_GlobalPartialView*.
Part of my ***_GlobalPartialView.cshtml***:

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>@result.Message</strong>
</div>
```

on my PartialView:

```
@Html.Partial(T4.Shared.Views._GlobalMessagesPartial)
```

On PartialView message show like this:
[image]

On View like this:
[image]

On View I can close alert box, but not an the PartialView. Why? How to solve it?

Comment: Are the styling and scripts from the Layout loaded correctly?

Answer (score 0):

There could be few reasons for this not working.

Just to make sure your JQuery is available to partial view, you can try adding jquery references in your partial view page. Hoping you don't have similar issue like this one http://forums.asp.net/t/1649526.aspx/1

refer this too [Jquery or Javascript problem in my partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888343/jquery-or-javascript-problem-in-my-partial-view)

Answer (score 0):

So this is fairly old, but I needed something like this, so I decided to post my solution.

**This is my Partial View:**

```
@* Message Box *@
@if (ViewBag.AlertMessage != null)
{
<div class="col-sm-12">

    @if (ViewBag.AlertDismissable == true)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-dismissible @ViewBag.AlertType" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            @ViewBag.AlertMessage
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="alert @ViewBag.AlertType" role="alert">@ViewBag.AlertMessage</div>
    }

    @*<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">@ViewBag.Message</div>*@

</div>
```

}

**I have some utility routines in my base class to setup the ViewBag:**

```
    public void SetBSViewBagAlert(bsAlertType alerttype, string message)
    {
        SetBSViewBagAlert(alerttype, message, false);
    }

    public void SetBSViewBagAlert(bsAlertType alerttype, string message, bool dismissable)
    {
        // Translate from enum to constant to avoid typos... 
        switch (alerttype)
        {
            case bsAlertType.success:
                ViewBag.AlertType = ALERT_SUCCESS;
                break;
            case bsAlertType.info:
                ViewBag.AlertType = ALERT_INFO;
                break;
            case bsAlertType.warning:
                ViewBag.AlertType = ALERT_WARNING;
                break;
            case bsAlertType.danger:
                ViewBag.AlertType = ALERT_DANGER;
                break;
            default:
                ViewBag.AlertType = ALERT_INFO;
                break;
        }

        ViewBag.AlertDismissable = dismissable;
        ViewBag.AlertMessage = message;
    }
```

**Once I know I have errors I set the message from the controller:**

```
SetBSViewBagAlert(bsAlertType.warning, ModelStateErrorsString(), true);
```

**This is the only line needed in the View:**

```
@Html.Partial("_AlertBoxPartial")
```

I'm still tweaking around with this.  If I make changes I'll post an update.